# Multiple apk's on play store for multiple feature testing

Tags: android, react-native, deployment, google-play, apk

We have different teams working on multiple features. The feature release dates for each team are simultaneous. I want to create a mechanism so that each team is able to push an apk to play store so the test team can test. After test confirms stability the apk will be moved to production.

Are there tools that help in doing this?

Comment: Maybe you need Jira or Bitbucket.

Comment: is QA environment directly test from Google play? or a mechanism is built locally for testing purpose. You need local mechanism.

Comment: try Internal Test

Comment: @DarShan we have a small test team, and the same apk updating with different features will cause a lot of confusion.

Comment: @farhana we test both locally and the from google play

Comment: you don't need google play just get the signed `apk` upload online and get the link and share that URL to QA

Comment: @AliAhmed, have considered jira ops, but am looking for more budget friendly or free options

Comment: for online uploading, you can use Dropbox and other services. and it is free too.

Comment: @farhana i am looking into ci system and have already integrated fastlane, manually uploading to dropbox moves away from that purpose, I was planning different internal tracks for different git branches but as a tester can only be in one test track at a time , there would be no point in doing so